# Getting empty result from eth_sendBundle on builder0x69

Tags: flashbots, mev-boost, mev-searcher

I need to send my bundle to builder0x69 block builder using `eth_sendBundle` RPC method, but I get a response message with an empty result. I could not find any documents related to that builder, but it's supposed to be permissionless and Flashbots compatible. Do I need to authenticate to use this builder? Do I need to send extra params or headers to `eth_sendBundle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `eth_sendBundle` works just fine despite returning an empty result field in the RPC response. It also does not support `eth_callBundle` to simulate bundle execution at the time.